# How to show a limit law for record times $N(n) = \min\{j: j > N(n-1), X_j > X_{N(n-1)}\}$, $X_n$ iid.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have the same question here which I asked a few days ago, but now I have really worked on it and I could not get the solution, so I need some more help.

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with continuous distribution function $F(x) = 1-\exp(-x)$, $x > 0$. Furthermore, define $N(1) := 1$ and for $n \ge 2$,
\begin{align*}
N(n) := \min\{j : j > N(n-1), X_j > X_{N(n-1)}\}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\log N(n) - X_{N(n)}|}{\log n} = 1
\end{align*}
almost surely.

In the textbook by Galambos is the following proof strategy, which I tried to understand.

1. The random variables $N(n)$ are conditionally independent, given the sequence $X_{N(k)}$, $k \ge 1$.
2. The conditional distribution of $N(n)$ is
   \begin{align*}
   P(N(n) > t \mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1) = (1 - \exp(- X_{N(n)}))^t.
   \end{align*}
3. From this fact, one gets at once by a Borel-Cantelli type of argument that
   \begin{align*}
   \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\log(N(n) \exp(-X_{N(n)}))|}{\log n} = 1
   \end{align*}
   almost surely, given the sequence $\{X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1\}$.
4. But, since the $\limsup$ is a constant, the same result is obtained if the condition is dropped.

What I have so far is 2.:
\begin{align*}
P(N(n) > t \mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1)
&= P(\max\{X_1, \ldots, X_t\} < X_{N(n)}\mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1) \\
&= P(Z_t < X_{N(n)} \mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1)
= (F(X_{N(n)}))^t \\
&= (1 - \exp(- X_{N(n)}))^t,
\end{align*}
where $Z_t := \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_t\}$.

Then, for 1. I need to show that
\begin{align*}
&P(N(n_1) \le t_1, N(n_2) \le t_2 \mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1) \\
&= P(N(n_1) \le t_1 \mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1) \cdot P(N(n_2) \le t_2 \mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1).
\end{align*}
One has
\begin{align*}
&P(N(n_1) \le t_1 \mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1) \cdot P(N(n_2) \le t_2 \mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1) \\
&= P(Z_{t_1} \ge X_{N(n_1)}\mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1) \cdot P(Z_{t_2} \ge X_{N(n_2)}\mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1) \\
&= (1 - P(Z_{t_1} < X_{N(n_1)}\mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1)) (1 - P(Z_{t_2} < X_{N(n_2)}\mid X_{N(k)}, k \ge 1)) \\
&= (1 - (F(X_{N(n_1)}))^{t_1}) (1 - (F(X_{N(n_2)}))^{t_2}) \\
&= (1 - (1 - \exp(- X_{N(n_1)}))^{t_1}) (1 - (1 - \exp(- X_{N(n_2)}))^{t_2}) \\
&= 1 - (1 - \exp(- X_{N(n_2)}))^{t_2} - (1 - \exp(- X_{N(n_1)}))^{t_1} \\
&\quad + (1 - \exp(- X_{N(n_1)}))^{t_1}(1 - \exp(- X_{N(n_2)}))^{t_2}
\end{align*}
I do not see how I can get the other end of the equation.

Then, for 3., I wanted to use a fact, which follows from the Borel-Cantelli Lemma:

> Let $X$ be a random variable and $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables over some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$. If $\sum_{n \ge 1} P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) < \infty$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, then $X_n \to X$ almost surely.

If I did not make a mistake, we have
\begin{align*}
&\left\{\left|\frac{|\log N(n) - X_{N(n)}|}{\log n} - 1\right| > \epsilon\right\}
= \left\{||\log N(n) - X_{N(n)}| - \log n| > \epsilon \log n\right\} \\
&= \left\{|\log N(n) - X_{N(n)}| > (\epsilon+1) \log n\right\} \cup \left\{|\log N(n) - X_{N(n)}| < (1 - \epsilon)\log n\right\} \\
&= \left\{N(n) > n^{\epsilon+1}  \exp(X_{N(n)})\right\} \cup \left\{N(n) < \exp(X_{N(n)})n^{-\epsilon-1}\right\}
\cup \left\{N(n) < n^{1 - \epsilon} \exp(X_{N(n)})\right\} \\
&\quad \cup \left\{N(n) > \exp(X_{N(n)}) n^{-1 + \epsilon}\right\}.
\end{align*}
So I wanted to split up the series in four single series and to show that they converge. But I can do this only with the first series (from which one can get a geometric series), but not with the other ones. My feeling is that there is a much simpler solution for this task.
4. is clear to me.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: What happened to the question this one duplicates?

Comment: I think I deleted it, because I was really confused there and I wrote things which did not make much sense. I forgot the edit button.

Comment: Were there already any comments and/or answers on this page you "inadvertently" deleted?

Comment: There was no answer written. Also no comments.

Comment: See my edit in the previous comment, please.